# Compute the integral of $f=\frac{1}{z^2}$ along the given contour $T$.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

My professor wrote the homework questions by hand so I posted screenshots for reference.
[image]

[image]

In office hours earlier today, my professor gave my friend the answer to b) claiming that it was 0. My friend then told me that the reason for this was $\int_{T}f = 0$ because the curve is closed. However I am finding it really hard to believe this answer.

What I ended up doing was using the fact that by Cauchy's theorem, the integral along $T$ is the same as the integral around 2 unit circles centered at $0$. Then I computed the contour integral and got a nonzero number.

I don't understand what theorem or property, or even intuitively looking at this picture why the answer would be 0. Any help/independent verification would be appreciated, thanks.

Edit: How I got my answer

Just FYI Our professor did NOT teach us about residues so that knowledge technically isn't known at this point.

By Cauchy's integral formula, we have

$$f(f(z)) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{T} \frac{f(u)}{u-z}du$$
where $f(u)$ is analytic on a region containing $T$ and its interior. Since the unit circle is contained in $T$, by Cauchy's theorem we can compute the integral along a double circle. This is what I attempted to do. Using the formula $$\int_{T}f(z)dz = \int_{a}^{b}f(z(t))z'(t)dt$$ where $z'(t) = rie^{it}$ and letting $C$ be the unit circle centered at $0$, I get

\begin{align*}
\int_{C}\frac{1}{z^2}z'(t)dt = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{r^2e^{2it}}rie^{it}dt = \frac{i}{r}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{e^{it}}dt = i\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{z}dt = 2k\pi i^2
\end{align*}
where we know from class that $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{z}dz = 2\pi i$ and the winding number is $k=2$ I got $-4\pi$ as my answer.

Comment: how did you get that non-zero number? I agree that one can deform the contour to a double circle, but $1/z^2$ has zero residue at its unique pole so its integral is zero on any closed curve that doesn't pass through the pole; or equivalently, $1/z^2$ has a primitive in the punctured plane and the result follows that way also

Comment: I updated to show my work, maybe you would be able to point out what was wrong in my integration process

Comment: Your penultimate step has an error. Evaluate the prior integral directly..

Comment: I swapped $\frac{1}{e^{it}}$ with $\frac{1}{z}$ because I thought they were equivalent but they aren't? ($z = re^{it}$ where $r=1$) and we showed in class that $\frac{1}{z} = 2\pi i$.

Comment: The problem is that you moved from $dt$ to $dz$ (where you say from class etc at the end) and that is incorrect as $dz=izdt$ direct evaluation reduces to integrate $\cos, \sin$ on the circle and those are zero by periodicity

Comment: By the way, your friend's answer of "$\int_T f=0$ because the curve is closed" is not the full justification. The full reason is that the curve is closed, and the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}$ has a primitive defined on $U=\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$; explicitly if $F(z)=\frac{-1}{z}$, then $F'=f$ on $U$ (or of course, you can use the residue theorem as explained above). Another common mistake is to say that the integral vanishes simply because the curve is closed, and the function is holomorphic on its domain; again this is not good enough (as evidenced by the function $z\mapsto \frac{1}{z}$).

Answer (score 1):

The function $\frac{1}{z^2}$ has a pole at $0$, so your gut feeling that using the closure of the curve is not sufficient for the integral to be $0$ is correct. In fact, for a different, but very similar function which also has a pole at $0$, the integral doesn't vanish: $\frac1z$.

In the comments it was said that $\frac{1}{z^2}$ has $0$ as a residue, so the integral vanishes. But philosophically speaking, that's the wrong way around: $\frac{1}{z^2}$ has $0$ residue *because* the integral along your given curve vanishes. If it didn't vanish, we'd have defined the residue differently, so it wouldn't be $0$.

The deeper reason why this integral vanishes is the fact that your function has an antiderivative. If a holomorphic function has an antiderivative on the entirety of its domain, then contour integrals only depend on the start and end points of the contour, which makes closed integrals vanish. And $\frac{1}{z^2}$ has an antiderivative: it's $-\frac{1}{z}$. In contrast, the example $\frac{1}{z}$ does not have an antiderivative on its entire domain. Such an antiderivative would have to be a holomorphic branch of the logarithm, but no such branch exists on the punctured plane $\mathbb C\backslash\{0\}$. That's why closed integrals over that function don't necessarily vanish.